# Out of bounds error matching cells in a matrix

Tags: java, matrix

This method is meant to find any cell that is matching two aligned cells and store them in a temporary matrix. However whenever I run the program, I get an out of bounds error. The matrix is 3x3. How can I make it stores any 3 matching adjacent cells in the tempMatrix.

public void matchMatrix(){

```
    int[][] tempMatrix = new int[rowsN][columnsM];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < matrixArr.length; i++){
        
        for(int j = 0; j < matrixArr.length; j++){
            
            if((matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i + 1][j] && matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i + 2][j]) || (matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i][j + 1] && matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i][j + 2])){
                tempMatrix[i][j] = matrixArr[i][j];
            }
        
        }
        
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < matrixArr.length; i++){
        
        for(int j = 0; j < matrixArr.length; j++){
            
            if(matrixArr[i][j] == tempMatrix[i][j]) System.out.println("[ ] ");
            else{
            System.out.print("[" + matrixArr[i][j] + "] ");
            }
        }
            System.out.println();
    }
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry I edited it into the OP its "How can I make it stores any 3 matching adjacent cells in the tempMatrix"

Answer (score 0):

```
matrixArr[i][j + 1]
```

The above code will access outside the last index of the 2D array during the last execution of the inner loop.

```java
    matrixArr[i + 1][j]
```

The above code will access outside the last index of the 2D array during the last execution of the outer loop.

Also, the code assumes that the 2D array is always a square matrix. `j < matrixArr.length` but initializes the tempMatrix as `tempMatrix = new int[rowsN][columnsM];`. This can also exception.

### How to fix out of bounds exception

Add explicit checks for boundary conditions

1. whenever `i + 2` is accessed ensure that the current index is atleast 2 lesser than last index

```java
        if (i < matrixArr.length - 2 && j < matrixArr[i].length - 2) {
            if ((matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i + 1][j] && matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i + 2][j])
                || (matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i][j + 1] && matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i][j + 2])) {
            }
        } else if (i < matrixArr.length - 2) {
            if (matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i + 1][j] && matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i + 2][j]) {
            }
        } else if (j < matrixArr[i].length - 2) {
            if (matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i][j + 1] && matrixArr[i][j] == matrixArr[i][j + 2]) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hmm I can see why that's happening now, but how else am I gonna tell it to store any matches?

Comment: one possible solution would be to add `if` checks to check for the boundary conditions

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you give me an example?

Comment: @JacobParratto, I have added a sample code

Comment: Ahhhh so thats what you meant. I see! Than you!